# How to define local connection to Spark Thrift in Power BI

Tags: apache-spark, powerbi, thrift

I am trying to configure the local connection to the Spark Thrift in Power BI. I am able to connect using Spark ODBC (localhost:10000 with mechanism User Name and Thrift transport SASL). But I would like to use Spark connector as it supports Direct Query.

[image: print screen]

I couldn't find how to define the connection string. Tried several things like localhost:10000/default/;transportMode=http;ssl=true;user=... but always get the error

```
ERROR TThreadPoolServer:297 - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status 80
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status 80
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:184)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
        ... 4 more
```

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. As written here https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Connect-Power-BI-to-Hadoop-Direct-query-HDFS-vs-Spark-vs-custom/td-p/374625
it just doesn't work in Power BI from Microsoft Store. It works in the app from the website.